# Add data from one table into another

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert

I have `table1` looking like:

```
col1   col2   col3
-------------------
foo    bar    baz
lorem  ipsum  dolor
```

And `table2` looking like:

```
col1     col2   col3     col4   col5
-----------------------------------------
sitting  onthe  dock     ofthe  bay
heard    it     through  the    grapevine
```

I want to import all data from `table1` into `table2`:

```
col1     col2   col3     col4   col5
-----------------------------------------
sitting  onthe  dock     ofthe  bay
heard    it     through  the    grapevine
foo      bar    baz
lorem    ipsum  dolor
```

Normally, if the data structure is the same, I would use below, but this doesn't work here (obviously).

```
select * into table2 from table1
```

What is the proper way of importing in this case?

Comment: Use an `INSERT` statement not an `INTO` clause. A quick search will show you how to use the syntax; it's a fundamental part of SQL.

Comment: Also if you did try an `INTO` it wouldn't work (obviously ;) ) as `table2` already exists; an `INTO` clause both creates the table and inserts the data too. If the table already exists the statement fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to specify the columns using the `Insert INTO`

```
Insert Into table2 (col1,col2,col3)
Select col1,col2,col3
  From table1
```

Comment: And explicitly specifying the columns for an  `INSERT` is generally regarded as an **accepted Best Practice** anyway - so get in the habit of doing this - **always** :-)